# Is there a way to set a asp.net button's CommandArgument in javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a GridView that lists a bunch of items and one of the columns has a link that displays a modal (AjaxToolkit ModalPopupExtender). Let's call that link "Show".  In that modal, I have a asp:button for saving the data entered in that modal.  Let's call that button "Save"

So when the user clicks on a "Show" link in a certain row, I'd like write some javascript that sets something in the "Save" button, so that in my code-behind, I can handle "Save".Command and use the CommandEventArgs parameter to get the value.

Is this possible, or do I just need to use a hidden input tag and set its value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, after continuing the research, it looks like it cannot be done.  The CommandArgument property might reside in the ViewState, but for this case, it is completely server side and cannot be changed using javascript.

Answer (score 23):

Not a direct answer to your question, but another possible way of solving the problem:

Place a `HiddenField` control on the page. In your code-behind, before displaying the modal popup, set the value of that control to the ID of the row that was clicked (or the row number, or some identifying value). Then in the code-behind of your Save button, you can just read the value of the `HiddenField`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Updatepanel, you need to place the **Hiddenfield inside the Updatepanel**. Otherwise you will not be able to get/set the value stored in hiddenfield.