# pass javascript value to asp.net function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

the question says it all : i have a linkbutton to which i pass through CommandArgument a value and i need that value to be a javascript value. Thanks!

Edit :

here is my linkbutton tag :

> < asp:linkbutton id="prevBut"
> runat="server"  OnCommand="load_com"
> CommandArgument=to_place_javascript_string
> Text="previous" />

and the function :

> public void load_com(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
>
> ```
> { //get the string from e and search through the database for something   }
> ```

i want to pass the name of a photo that is stored in a variable $.galleria.current.

Comment: Code. Code. Code. Or just keep us guessing, that's OK too.

Comment: An code example would be great! Try to provide them always in your questions :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to set a asp.net button's CommandArgument in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593039/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-asp-net-buttons-commandargument-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop for a moment and think about what the LinkButton is actually doing.  It's not magic.  It's just posting the form for you.

As such, you can...

- define an onsubmit handler to stuff that javascript value into a hidden form field
- or, replace that LinkButton with a simple <a onclick="dostuff()"> pointing at a function that stuffs your value into a hidden form field and submits the form
- or, replace that LinkButton with a simple <a onclick="dostuff()"> pointing at a function that constructs a URL containing ?myvalue=whatever and redirects to it.

There's no reason you need to involve ASP:LinkButton in any of it.  If the built-in ASP.NET controls aren't doing what you want.  All you need to do is stop using them.

*(Incidentally, you'll have a much happier and more productive career in the .NET world if you stop using Microsoft's Rich Controls in favor of their HTML equivalents.  Those things are there so that non-programmers can drag/drop their way to unmaintainable websites.  Since you're here, we can assume you're not a non-programmer, and are therefore smart enough to ignore the marketing portions of ASP.NET and use the good stuff directly.)*

Comment: Thanks! I'll stop using them :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to place a string of javascript code in the command argument or a value which can be accessed via javascript?

If you need a value to be accessible via javascript you could put the command argument value in an attribute of the linkbutton  `<a href="javascript:void(null)" commandArg="value" >Link Text</a>` this would make "commandArg" available via jQuery like `$('#linkID').attr('commandArg')` . You could obviously name that attrubute whatever you need to.